# Spring mvc: is there a way to call another controller, get the response and fill it to a model attribute?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two mvc style endpoints returning templatefile names as view names, in the same classpath: /source and /target. The source_template has a variable which needs to be filled by contents of another template, say target_template.

```
@RestController
class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/source")
    public String source(Model model) {       
        model.addAttribute("attr1", /*call endpoint /target and add the response of parsed template 'target_template' here */);

        return "source_template";
    }

    @GetMapping("/target")
    public String target(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("attr2", "good");
        //may be continue the nested invocation n number of times
        return "target_template";
    }
}
```

given the source_template.html:
Hai, $attr1
and the target_template.html:
this has been a $attr2 day

having said, i invoke the url /source, I should get "Hai, this has been a good day".

I can just call the target() method directly, but that would not render the template. Or I should directly use the templating engine apis to link the template file, put the context object, parse the template and return the string , which defeats the whole purpose of spring mvc. Or I can use resttemplate, but that requires an absolute url, and performance would take a hit. So, is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: use `return "redirect:" + YOUR_BASE_PATH + "/target"`

Comment: @ErfanAhmed, thanks for your comment. but using redirect will ignore model attributes that are set prior to redirect and ignore the source_template too.

Comment: @SiddhArth you can pass your model attributes using `flashAttributes`. Or you can use a command obj, update the command obj at `/source` then `redirect` to `/target` and get the command obj back using `comamndId`